# How do i retrieve the value if input got checked

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve the value if input got checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="check" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<button>Submit</button>
```

in script i try,

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input").name;
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
btn.onclick = function () {
    if (a.checked == true) {
        console.log(a.value);
    }
};
```

Do i need to put an "id" in each input?
I want pure javascript because i already know the jQuery code.

Comment: Well, jQuery’s selector function is different than Javascript’s because `document.getElementsByTagName` gives you a `NodeList`, not an element. None of `var a = …` and `var btn = …` are needed at that point, nor are they correct. For the button a selector like `document.querySelector('button')` is more suitable, if that one’s the only button on the page. Then read the duplicate target to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** to get checked element. Also **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** returns  **[`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** so you need to pick first one using index otherwise you need to give an `id` then use **[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
// getting first button from HTMLCollection
btn.onclick = function() {
// binding click event handler
  var a = document.querySelector('[name="radioGroup"]:checked');
  // getting checked checkbox
  if (a) {
  // checking a is defined or not , if not it means no checked buttons are there
    console.log(a.value);
    // logging it's value in console
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="check" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
btn[0].onclick = function () {
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       if (a[i].checked == true) {
          console.log(a[i].value);
       }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On Button Click You can use **querySelector** to get Your result.
Following code will help.

```
function GetSelected()
{
   alert(document.querySelector('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked').value);
}


<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="check" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="wrong" />
<button onclick="GetSelected()">Submit</button>
```